# Content-Security-Policy header/meta for hCaptcha not working

Tags: security, web, browser, content-security-policy

I'm trying to embed hCaptcha into a website, but it won't accept the Content-Security-Policy I set in the meta head or by setting the header directly in Chrome and FireFox.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com; frame-src 'self' https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com" />
```

More readable format:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com;
frame-src 'self' https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://hcaptcha.com https://*.hcaptcha.com
```

It's the same string for the header (using Go). Right now I'm just trying to get the meta tag to work. This is the error I get in Chrome:

[image]

And in FireFox:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I think it started with the latest Chrome and FireFox update and worked before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by configuring and using a different hostname. Add localhost.com to /etc/hosts and access your page on localhost.com:port.

Comment: Oh, did you debug РCaptcha on localhost? hCAPTCHA prohibits `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`: https://docs.hcaptcha.com/#localdev. And pls note, CSP from this page https://docs.hcaptcha.com/#cspsettings is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I tried. It works if you add a custom hostname to /etc/hosts though and that's fine to me. No CPS settings required.